# why is minecraft pi gone?

Tags: raspbian, minecraft

i installed Raspbian or Debian 10 Buster on my computer, and saw that minecraft pi is not there anymore... i used older Raspbian version before not sure which one but it had minecraft pi on it. Was it removed in the later versions?

Comment: Maybe this would help: [https://www.minecraft.net/en-us/edition/pi](https://www.minecraft.net/en-us/edition/pi) "Minecraft: Pi Edition runs on Raspbian Wheezy with XWindows"

Comment: I don't know why you'd need a "Pi Edition" anyhow because the regular edition is just a Java jarfile to execute.

Answer (score 0):

An [older article](https://minecraft.fandom.com/wiki/Pi_Edition) says:

> Pi Edition never received any subsequent updates and is no longer updated.

So it makes sense to be removed from newer releases.